# How to use a single variable which can have multiple data types in C++

Tags: c++

How can a variable have 2 data types? If "month" is a variable and it should be take from input with std::cin. What should I do so that the user can enter a string like "January" or enter an integer like 1?

Comment: Use `std::string` for month variable and validate after user enters by checking if it's "January" or "1"

Comment: Simple, choose one internal representation for your program (I suggest an `int` from 1 to 12, for instance). Then read the users input as a string and **convert** what the user entered to whatever internal representation you have chosen.

Comment: The user types input as **text**. Nothing else. It's up to your program to decide whether the text that the user typed is a valid representation of whatever it is that you're looking for. So look at the text and decide what to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ 17 we got something called std::variant it is basicaly a type safe union
to use it you just declare the types you need:

```
std::variant<int, std::string> data;

data = "Hello!";
data = 13;
// No Compilation Issues
```

The Hard Part Is When You Want To Retrieve The Data

```
std::string& text = std::get<std::string>(data):
int& number = std::get<int>(data);
```

BUT MAKE SURE THE LAST THING YOU DEFINED IT AS IS THE TYPE YOU ARE TRYING TO RETRIEVE MEANING:

```
data = 13;
std::string& text = std::get<std::string>(data); // Bad Exception Error
```

A better thing is to use std::get_if

```
if (auto temp = std::get_if<std::string>(&data);
    std::string& text = *temp; // do what ever you want
```

I Hope this answerd Your Question Happy Coding!

Comment: `std::visit` is generally better.

Comment: have an upvote for answering the question literally. It can be a source of frustration when looking for a Q&A and all you find is the exact question but answers that say "dont do it" which is what I did in my answer. Nevertheless, I wouldn't use a `std::variant<int,std::string>` for a `month` and I am also convinced that OP shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

> How can a variable have 2 data types?

It cannot. An object has one type. A single type can represent values of different types (unions,`std::variant`). However, you do not need it here. Whether the user enters `1` or `"January"` shouldn't matter, because it is both the same month.

> What should I do so that the user can enter a string like "January" or enter an integer like 1?

When you read user input, read it as a `std::string`. Internally you can use an enum:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum class month { January, February, Mazember};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, month& m){
    std::string temp;
    in >> temp;
    if (temp == "1" || temp == "January") { 
        m = month::January;
    }
    //...
    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const month& m) {
    if (m == month::January) {
        out << "January";
    }
    //...
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    month m;
    std::cin >> m;
    std::cout << m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration will conflict. You can't declare two different data types with a single identifier. For example, `std::string month` and `int month` will throw an error. Look at the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int month = 2;
    std::string month = "January"; // confliction
}
```

You'll get something:

```
error: conflicting declaration 'std::string month'
    5 |     std::string month = "January";
      |                 ^~~~~
vectors.cpp:4:9: note: previous declaration as 'int month'
    4 |     int month = 2;
      |         ^~~~~
```

You can overload functions, but not variables.

Answer (score 0):

`std::any` from c++17 also works.

Here is a little usage example.

```
//DECLARE ANY VARIABLE.
std::any month;

//GET THE INPUT.
std::string in;
std::cout << "Enter Something : " << std::endl;
std::cin >> in;

//STORE AS AN INTEGER.
if (in == "1")
    month = std::stoi(in);

//STORE AS A STRING
if (in == "January")
    month = in;
```